# Focus-follows-mouse conflicts with Resharper navigation

Tags: windows-7, focus, resharper, mouseleave

In Windows 7, you can give focus to a window just by hovering over it with the mouse. This feature is not enabled by default, but you can enable it in the Control Panel. (Here is the path to take:

[Ease of Access Center-->Make the mouse easier to use-->check "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse"]).

I like this feature a lot, but sometimes it annoys me when I try to open a C# class in Visual Studio using Resharper. I'll hit CTRL+N and type the name of the class I want to see (for example, "MyWpfClass"). Resharper will then show a dropdown of suggestions with "MyWpfClass" on top. I hit return, and now Resharper opens a dropdown which lets me choose between "MyWpfClass.xaml" and "MyWpfClass.xaml.cs". However, if the mouse cursor is in the wrong place, the dropdown closes within a second and I'm back to square one. Is there a way to fix this without turning the focus-follows-mouse feature off?

Comment: Though I am entirely not sure whether this is ReSharper's responsibility, I would recommend opening an issue at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem with MS Outlook: the auto-suggestions list for contacts would close automatically because Windows treated it as a window rather than part of the New Message window.

You could use NiftyWindows, which has the same option "Focus Follows Mouse", accessible through its context menu.

Alternatively, as it is written in Autohotkey, you could use extract and run its subroutine "XWN_FocusHandler" into a standalone script:

```
#Persistent 
#SingleInstance force
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn All, OutputDebug ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTimer, XWN_FocusHandler, 100
return

XWN_FocusHandler:
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, XWN_MouseX, XWN_MouseY, XWN_WinID
    If ( !XWN_WinID )
        Return

    If ( (XWN_MouseX != XWN_MouseOldX) or (XWN_MouseY != XWN_MouseOldY) )
    {
        IfWinNotActive, ahk_id %XWN_WinID%
            XWN_FocusRequest = 1
        Else
            XWN_FocusRequest = 0

        XWN_MouseOldX := XWN_MouseX
        XWN_MouseOldY := XWN_MouseY
        XWN_MouseMovedTickCount := A_TickCount
    }
    Else
        If ( XWN_FocusRequest and (A_TickCount - XWN_MouseMovedTickCount > 500) )
        {
            WinGetClass, XWN_WinClass, ahk_id %XWN_WinID%
            If ( XWN_WinClass = "Progman" )
                Return

            ; checks wheter the selected window is a popup menu
            ; (WS_POPUP) and !(WS_DLGFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME)
            WinGet, XWN_WinStyle, Style, ahk_id %XWN_WinID%
            If ( (XWN_WinStyle & 0x80000000) and !(XWN_WinStyle & 0x4C0000) )
                Return

            IfWinNotActive, ahk_id %XWN_WinID%
                WinActivate, ahk_id %XWN_WinID%

            XWN_FocusRequest = 0
        }
Return
```